# How to extract a link from a href based on class?

Tags: javascript, python, html, dom

I'm George beginner in programming world and I need some help in this project.

So I'm building a script that at the end of it I want to redirect (*on the same tab not in a new one*) to the link (*in this page is link.com in another page is link1.com and so on*) inside of a href based on element class(*e.g. class name aaa* )

Every time the link is different but the class is always the same name : aaa (the class always contains only one link).

The methods I've tried seems to work only with clicks and copy the current pages url.

```
let url = location.href;
document.getElementsByClassName('aaa').innerHTML = url;
```

Only suitable extracting method I've found was Pythons BeautifulSoup Library.

Any thoughts on how am I going to extract the link ?

Thanks in advance.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [querySelctor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (or [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) if you have multiple link elements) to get references to the DOM elements that contain the link(s).

Then use [`getAttribute("href")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the actual link value e.g. `https://www.wikipedia.org/` and finally [redirect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp) using `window.location.replace("https://www.wikipedia.org/")`.

Here a small working example which should give you an idea how this could work.

```js
const linkElement = document.querySelector(".aaa"); // only return the first element with that class
const link = linkElement.getAttribute("href")
console.log("Doing some other stuff...")
console.log("You will be redirected in 2 seconds...")
setTimeout(() => window.location.replace(link), 2000);
```

```html
<a class="aaa" href="https://www.wikipedia.org/">
  <div>Something inside</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript code solves your problem:

```
var link = document.querySelector('.aaa').getAttribute('href');
console.log(link);
```

Good luck!